# file not being fully uploaded to server - js

Tags: javascript, express, file

I am uploading files to my server using a system in which it would splice a part of the file (returning a `Blob`), convert to base64, and then upload to the server.

However, it seems to be only uploading the start of the file as when the base64 was turned back into the file, it was only 30sec long (audio) compared to the 4 minutes of the original file.

```js
async function uploadFile(file) {
    const chunkSize = 500 * 1024; // 500kb chunk size
    let currentPosition = 0;
    currentUID = generateUID()


    while (currentPosition < file.size) {
        const chunk = file.slice(currentPosition, currentPosition + chunkSize);
        currentPosition += chunk.size;

        const base64Chunk = await readChunkAsBase64(chunk);

        await uploadChunk(base64Chunk, channelId);
        
        // progress info code ...
    }
}
```

```js
async function uploadChunk(chunk) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Uploading chunk: ${chunk.substring(0, 25)}...`);
            fetch(`/upload/${currentUID}`, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ chunk: chunk })
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => resolve(data))
        }, 50); // update delay
    });
}

function readChunkAsBase64(chunk) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result.split(',')[1]);
        reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
        reader.readAsDataURL(chunk);
    });
}
```

I revied the base64 data from the uploaded version and the original version and the file isn't as long, nor is all the base64 data in the uploaded version.

**Chunk size + `currentPosition`**
(`chunk.size` followed by `currentPosition`

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `chunk.size` with each iteration?  Is it possibly `0` ?  That would seem to be consistent with the results you are seeing.  Consider logging both `chunk.size` and `currentPosition` within your loop to see what they are becoming.

Comment: @GregFenton Just updated with values of chunkSize and currentPosition

Comment: Err....what makes you think those are the same chunks each and every time?  There will be some common initial characters due to the way that Base64 encoding works...but look at the latter part of the strings, not the initial parts.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes sense. I didn't notice because the start looked the same. But then I guess the problem turns that it wasn't uploading the whole file. I assumed it was just the same chunks as when the base64 was turned back into the file it was only 30sec long (audio file) compared to the 4 minutes long. I'll update the question